# webpack vue compiler in 1 file in .net mvc5 environment

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I have a MVC5 .Net solution which is using Vue.js and webpack to compile. on the early days of the project someone decided to compile the .vue in separated .js files. But now with over 20 .vue files, it's a pain. My question is:

How can I transform this webpack config to compile it in a single .js file?

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

// build an object that looks like 
// {
//      "filename": "./filename.vue"
// }
// to list the entry points for webpack to compile.
function buildEntry() {
    const reducer = (entry, file) => { entry[file.split(".").shift()] = 
`./Vue/${file}`; return entry; };

    return fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "Vue"))
         .filter(file => file.endsWith(".vue"))
         .reduce(reducer, {});
}

module.exports = {
    entry: buildEntry(),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "Vue"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        library: "[name]"
    },
    module: {
         loaders: [
             { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue-loader' },
        ],
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try having a single entry point.
To do this have a JS file in which you use import or require what your application needs.

If you have multiple independent small Vue apps, I guess you'll have to make multiple webpack configurations.

Edit: I highly recommend you use the Vue CLI to setup a basic project from their template and then digging into it to understand the Webpack setup and such. https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/tree/develop/template.

Comment: I have just 1 vue aplication, I will try it see if I can make it work

Comment: Do you have any examples, or a link where I can see how this entry point has to be written?

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/src/main.js. It's the one that the vue CLI uses as a template.If you ignore the templating elements, you see it imports Vue, the router and other stuff and mounts the main Vue intance. The router would usually define routes to other components and therefore import them there. Therefore chaining the dependencies. This way by using a single entry point everything else that's used in the tree of dependencies will be bundled up nicely.